# E: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2

Tags: updates, gnupg

when i try to update i see this erroIgn http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal

```
InRelease                                 
Ign http:*//archive.canonical.com lucid InRelease                               
Ign http:*//security.ubuntu.com quantal-security InRelease                      
Ign http:*//ir.archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease                             
Ign http:*//ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease                                 
Hit http:*//archive.canonical.com lucid Release.gpg                             
Hit http:*//security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg                    
Ign http:*//ir.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates InRelease                     
Get:1 http:*//dl.google.com stable InRelease [1,540 B]                          
Hit http:*//ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg                               
Hit http:*//archive.canonical.com lucid Release                                 
Hit http:*//security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release                        
Ign http:*//ir.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports InRelease                   
Ign http:*//ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg                               
Hit http:*//archive.canonical.com lucid/partner Sources                         
Hit http:*//security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main amd64 Packages            
Hit http:*//ir.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg                           
Get:2 http:*//dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [1,540 B]                        
Ign https:*//private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease                        
Hit http:*//ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release                                   
Hit http:*//archive.canonical.com lucid/partner amd64 Packages                  
Hit http:*//security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted amd64 Packages      
Hit http:*//ir.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg                   
Ign http:*//ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release                                   
Hit http:*//archive.canonical.com lucid/partner i386 Packages                   
Hit http:*//security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe amd64 Packages        
Get:3 http:*//ir.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release.gpg [933 B]       
Get:4 http:*//dl.google.com stable Release [1,540 B]                            
Ign http:*//dl.google.com stable Release                                        
**E: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
r**
```

thank you before your answer